# Magento Mobile site to full site redirection

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mobile

I have multi domain magento website. Like www.domain.com for desktop and m.domain.com for mobile.

I have used following code to detect mobile devices and redirect `to m.domain.com, which is working fine`, but when need to come to www.domain.com with link like http://www.domain.com/?___store=default `it goes in redirect loop. how to fix it`

Your help appreciate.`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !___store=default  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !track=default [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://m.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301] [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:mobile]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ___store=default  [NC]    
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/ [L,R=301] [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:base,CO=track:default:%{HTTP_HOST}]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !___store=mobileview  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} track=default [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/ [L,R=301] [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:base]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ___store=mobileview  [NC]    
RewriteRule (.*) http://m.domain.com/$1 [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:mobile,CO=track:mobile:%{HTTP_HOST}]`
```

Answer (score 0):

Jennifer,try below

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.domain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but what you sent is redirect desktop site to mobile site, which is already working fine, i want come back to desktop site from mobile, which goes in loop

Answer (score 0):

Solution,
When you click the mobile site link goto normal version add a browser cookie.

The you can check the cookie availability and redirect.

Comment: Nir Thanks for the reply. can you please give syntax for it